# Is there a function to check if an array key exists, and get the value if it does, in one call?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to avoid scanning the array twice. Something like [TryGetValue in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @JohnConde You mean write my own function with a for loop?

Comment: Just get the value. And then check to see if you got anything.

Comment: use array_key_exists() and if it does use the key to get the value. That's it.

Comment: short if : isset($array[$key)?$array[$key]:null;

Comment: I want to avoid errors/warnings (i.e. your "just get the value and see if I got anything" suggestion) and I want to avoid scanning the array twice (check for key, and then get the value with the key).

Comment: If the array is addressed by integer index, and contains only consecutive values, meeting the criteria for a plain ordered array, only a bounds check is performed, no scan happens.
If the array is hash-based, as bucket lookup is performed, possibly twice. There may be some internal iterator or cache state that arrays hold behind the scene, though.
See my answer below.

Comment: @jszobody gave the best answer in a comment above - I've [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039491/199364) that expands on that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This is not recommended practice. Because `@` suppresses all exceptions in that expression.

However, AFAIK, it is the only efficient way to meet OP's stated criteria (see comment on question):

> I want to avoid errors/warnings and I want to avoid scanning the array twice.

Recommended practice can be seen in [Amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359427/199364).

That is, **don't** "micro-optimize" your code. Don't be so concerned about "scanning the array twice". Write clean, robust code. Later, if testing finds a performance problem, evaluate then how to improve performance.

**Do** handle errors and unexpected conditions (exceptions).

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

@jszobody gave an answer in a comment on the question. Expanding on his comment:

What do you want to return, if the array key doesn't exist?

If `null`, then one approach is "**just do it**":

```
@$array[$key]
```

("@" suppresses warning.)

If something else, and you **don't** store null values in array - so you don't ever want `null` to be returned - then this code becomes:

```
@$array[$key] ?? $YourDefaultValue
```

Unless your design BOTH 1) allows storing of `null` values in the array, AND 2) wants a default other than `null`. If both of these conditions are true, then you would need to explicitly test whether the key exists, using `array_key_exists`.

Comment: Just don't promote bad practice. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php

Comment: Please do not use the STFU operator.

Comment: I don't disagree with above comments - but OP says in comment *"I want to avoid errors/warnings and I want to avoid scanning the array twice"*. AFAIK, this is the only way in PHP to meet those two criteria efficiently. Indeed, the consequence is that exceptions are fully suppressed during that line of code. Therefore, I am not recommending doing what I show - consider it a last resort. If there is any way in a more recent PHP version to safely get the equivalent behavior (C#'s TryGetValue), then please add that as an answer to the question. Regardless, thank you for pointing out the downside.

Comment: `@` is not necessary when using the null coalescing operator (`??`).

Comment: You are saying that even if `$key` does not exist in `$array`, the warning is not generated when used before `??`. That sounds vaguely familiar; do you have a doc link for that?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a built-in function that does what you want. However, it's not hard to write a new one:

```
function tryGetValue($array, $key) {
    return (array_key_exists($key, $array)) ? $array[$key] : NULL;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz', 'bak', 'bam');

var_dump(tryGetValue($array, 'foo'));   // string(3) "bar"
var_dump(tryGetValue($array, 's'));     // NULL
var_dump(tryGetValue($array, 2));       // string(3) "bam"
var_dump(tryGetValue($array, 4));       // NULL
```

Comment: Will that scan the array twice?

Comment: I don't need to scan the array twice. In your function you first check if the key exists (1st scan) and then you get the value with $array[$key] (2nd scan). For performance, I want to avoid scanning twice.

Comment: how does it know if the key exists without scanning the array?

Comment: it must scan the array in order to check if the key exists.

Comment: You don't understand. HOW does the php function `array_key_exists` check if the key exists??? It SCANS THE ARRAY.

Comment: As explained in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675753/php-fastest-way-to-handle-undefined-array-key) similar question, yes: it requires 2 lookup in the B-TREE: One to check existence, another to retrieve value.

Comment: To future readers: Despite the upvotes, this does NOT meet the criteria specified in question. Please read the above comments, to know what you are getting with this! Does it "work"? Of course. Does it avoid the inefficiency of "scanning the array twice". No.

Answer (score -1):

Check these microbenchmarks I created [on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/lmaPR).

Here are the functions.

```
function tryGetValue1( $array, $key, Closure $default ) {
  return array_key_exists($key, $array)
    ? $array[$key] : $default();
}

function tryGetValue2( $array, $key, Closure $default ) {
  return ($value = @$array[$key]) !== null || array_key_exists($key, $array)
    ? $value : $default();
}

function tryGetValue3( $array, $key, Closure $default ) {
  return isset($array[$key]) || array_key_exists($key, $array)
    ? $array[$key] : $default();
}

function tryGetValueNotNull1( $array, $key, Closure $default ) {
  return ($value = @$array[$key]) !== null
    ? $value : $default();
}

function tryGetValueNotNull2( $array, $key, Closure $default ) {
  return isset($array[$key])
    ? $array[$key] : $default();
}
```

It depends on if you care about null, and what version of PHP you're using.

Looks like the compilers try to optimize toward the isset and array_key_exists operations, at least for small arrays. This might imply that arrays have their own internal iterator state for this and similar purposes.

Interestingly, you can combine isset and array_key_exists (see tryGetValue3) and come out ahead sometimes.

This isn't a fully appropriate benchmark, as there are no null existing keys defined in the test array. Feel free to expand on the example. :)

Comment: Note that if the default value you want is `null`, it isn't necessary to do any of the above, so no need to call a function: its as simple as: [`@$array[$key]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039491/199364).