# What is the fastest and most effective way to make comparisons (PHP)

Tags: php, performance

I would like to know what is the quickest and most effective way to make comparisons.
This will be more meaningful with my code:

```
public function exampleChangeVariable ($variable) {

  if ($variable == 'notif_received_title') {
    $variable = _('Text 1');
  }
  else if ($variable == 'notif_inprogress_title') {
    $variable = _('Text 2');
  }
  else if ($variable == 'notif_preparation_title') {
    $variable = _('Text 3');
  }
  else if ($variable == 'notif_positif_title') {
    $variable = _('Text 4');
  }
  else if ($variable == 'notif_negatif_title') {
    $variable = _('Text 5');
  }
  else if ($variable == 'notif_accepted_title') {
    $variable = _('Text 6');
  }
  else if ($variable == 'notif_rejected_title') {
    $variable = _('Text 7');
  }

  return $variable;
}
```

This function is found in a `foreach` (data recovered in database) and I would like to optimize it to the maximum.

- Should I instead use numbers as a variable?
- If I want to use text variables, is length important? (`notif_received_title` would be `received`)
- The `else if` is a good choice?
- How could I do better? (knowing he could have about twenty `if`)

Comment: This doesn't look like code that would cause a bottleneck so optimizing it won't get much more out of it (if it gets anything). Using an array mapping would certainly make it cleaner though.

Comment: I say use a lookup array.  The possible dupe isn't using keys and values like I'd recommend. But this is definitely a duplicate of many questions on this site.  Please research before posting a question.

Comment: IMHO Trying to come up with a generic - 'this way is best' answer is impossible without coming down to being an opinion.

Comment: I would also suggest if the data is coming from the database, that is likely to be the biggest performance problem and this is trivial in comparison.

Comment: This is a [tag:micro-optimisation].  The effect on performance would be negligible no matter what approach you used, unless you're processing literally millions of data points in a loop (though some methods might be easier for a programmer to read than others).

Comment: So you think that no matter how I do it will not change much? Does reducing the size of the texts to be compared have an impact?

Comment: @Rocstar Yes, that is probably the biggest factor in how fast this will be.  A 2gb file will take twice as long to process as a 1gb file.  If at all possible you should split the file into chunks and process each one individually.  On a multi-core system you can run the the processes simultaneously and get a much bigger performance win.

Comment: @GordonM would you mind adding this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675753/php-fastest-way-to-handle-undefined-array-key please?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I'd just make an associative array and fetch the right index.

Your code would become :

```
public function exampleChangeVariable($variable)
    {

        $assoc = [
            'notif_received_title'    => 'Text 1',
            'notif_inprogress_title'  => 'Text 2',
            'notif_preparation_title' => 'Text 3',
            'notif_positif_title'     => 'Text 4',
            'notif_negatif_title'     => 'Text 5',
            'notif_accepted_title'    => 'Text 6',
            'notif_rejected_title'    => 'Text 7'
        ];

        if (array_key_exists($variable, $assoc)) {
            return $assoc[$variable];
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Although there would still be room for improvement ( since keys have similar patterns )

Comment: in_array is the wrong function.  I think you mean array_key_exists or possibly even isset

Comment: The code is more "clean", 
Does reducing the size of the texts to be compared have an impact?

Comment: @GordonM Right, my bad, I edited the answer.
@ Rocstar No, it does not, just reduces redundancy.

Comment: Gordon is right.  I don't like this answer.  I would be using isset over array_key_exists' check for nulls is not necessary.