# Is searching a huge associative array with binary search faster than accessing via array key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a dictionary loaded into an assoc array. Elements are sorted, and there are a million Items. The dictionary is in the form term = > definition. Would it be quicker to search for a definition by using array($term) to access the key, or doing a binary search on the array? Would it be quicker over single pass or multiple term searches?

Comment: Internally PHP uses a  [hash table](https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html) to access an element in an array by key. Generally a hash lookup is faster that binary search, [but not always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360040/which-is-faster-hash-lookup-or-binary-search)

Comment: is hash table is linear way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a million items, do not use an associative array, but use a database. The fastest way to access an array is [isset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675753/php-fastest-way-to-handle-undefined-array-key)